# Why am I not reaching the base case in my pivot sorting algorithm?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, pivot

I'm getting a stack overflow exception trying to construct a sorting algorithm for linked lists. There my sort gets stuck at the same pivot indefinitely, and I can't figure out why it doesn't reach the base case.

//Intlist is a simple singly linked list class with an int var ".item" and a .next pointer

```
 pivotS(Intlist thisList){
    if (thisList == null || thisList.next == null){
      return thisList;
    } else{
      int pivot = thisList.item;
      Intlist lower = lowerThanPivot(pivot, thisList);
      Intlist upper = greaterOrEqualPivot(pivot, thisList);
      lower = pivotS(lower);
      upper = pivotS(upper);
      return appendLists(lower, upper);
    }
  }
```

This should work similarly to a Merge Sort in construction, right? My individual functions seem to work fine. Am I just setting up the recursion wrong?

Comment: Where's the return type.

Comment: Can you post lowerThanPivot() or greaterOrEqualPivot()? I'm thinking it's a problem with iterating over the list (maybe you're skipping elements by not resetting the iterator or something), seeing as the iterator is built into the actual list class as far as I can tell, and you never mentioned any methods other than .next and .item

Comment: This one finds the members with .item strictly lower than pivot. 

public static Intlist lowerThanPivot(int n, Intlist L){
    if (L == null){
      return L;
    }
    else if (L.item >= n ){
      return lowerThanPivot(n, L.next);
    } 
    else{
      return new Intlist(L.item, lowerThanPivot(n, L.next)); 
    }
  }

Comment: There's a version of lowerThanPivot that I was using. PivotS is static and returns Intlist.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a list consisting of two copies of the number 137, and let's see what this algorithm would do.

First, you'd look at the first element and notice that it exists (it's not null) and that the list doesn't have just one element (the next pointer isn't null either). You then split the first item as a pivot, so the pivot is 137.

Now, look at what happens next. The `lower` list consists of all the elements less than the pivot, which in this case is the empty list. The `upper` list consists of all elements greater than or equal to the pivot, which in this case is both of the copies of 137. You then recursively call `pivotS` on both lists. However, there's a problem here - the `upper` list is equal to the original list that you needed to sort, so that recursion proceeds exactly the same way as before. This ultimately leads to a stack overflow.

To fix this, update your code to split the input list into *three* groups - elements less than the pivot, elements equal to the pivot, and elements greater than the pivot. This might look something like this:

```
pivotS(Intlist thisList){
    if (thisList == null || thisList.next == null){
      return thisList;
    } else{
      int pivot = thisList.item;
      Intlist lower = lowerThanPivot(pivot, thisList);
      Intlist equal = equalToPivot(pivot, thisList);
      Intlist upper = greaterThanPivot(pivot, thisList);
      return appendLists(appendLists(pivotS(lower), equal), pivotS(upper);
    }
  }
```